# Is the morphism of sheaves $(R \mapsto GL(R((h)))) \rightarrow (R \mapsto PGL(R((h))))$ surjective in Zariski topology?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, ct.category-theory, sheaf-theory

Consider two functors given by $R \mapsto GL(R((h)))$ and $R \mapsto PGL(R((h)))$ for a ring $R$. It is easy to see that these functors are sheaves in Zariski topology (in fact for any affine variety $Y$ the functor $R \mapsto Y(R((h)))$ is a sheaf). Is the morphism of sheaves $(R \mapsto GL(R((h)))) \rightarrow (R \mapsto PGL(R((h))))$ surjective in Zariski topology?

Comment: Welcome new contributor.  No, that morphism of Zariski sheaves is not surjective.  There is a discussion of this in Serre's "Galois cohomology".

Comment: @JasonStarr thanks a lot! But could you be a little more specific? In which chapter can I find this discussion?

Comment: I do not have a copy of the book with me, but it should be prior to the long exact sequence of non-Abelian cohomology.  For instance, if $R$ equals $\mathbb{C}[x,y]/\langle y^2-x^2(x-1)\rangle$, the $n$-torsion elements in the Picard group give counterexamples.

Comment: Dear @JasonStarr, I am confused. I've looked it up in the Serre`s book and have not find information concerning this question. To this point I am not sure that I formulated it clear enough. My question is the following. For any ring $R$
 an element in $PGL(R((h)))$ defines a line bundle $L$ on $Spec(R((h)))$. I wonder whether it is true that there exists an open covering  $Spec R = \cup Spec R_{f_i}$ such that pullbacks of $L$ to $Spec(R_{f_i}((h)))$ are trivial. 

I don't see why your ring provides a counterexample, so I will be grateful if you explain it in more details.

Comment: You are correct, and I am incorrect.  I misread the question.  I thought you were just asking about surjectivity of the group homomorphism from $\textbf{GL}(R((h))$ to $\textbf{PGL}(R((h))$.  Now I see that is not what you are asking.  Sorry for the confusion.